# How to stop Ubuntu from talking to me?

Tags: 13.10, text-to-speech, orca

The title may sound silly, but on Ubuntu 13.10, I'm getting frequent audible notifications using text to speech.

Is this the "speech dispatcher" and how can I disable it?

Comment: `Settings > Universal Access > Screen Reader > Off/On`

Comment: There might be a new icon in the top bar. If you click on it you can enable/disable several things, like the screen reader. ([the Icon looks like this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/figures/preferences-desktop-accessibility-symbolic.svg))

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> will disable or enable speech dispatcher.

The last thing you should hear is "screen reader off" :-

ps. The Super key is the "windows" key...

Comment: many thanks! I'm almost gone nuts already
Still didn't manage to find a corresponding setting to disable it completely in Linux mint 19.3
Tried 'universal', 'seeing', 'read', 'speech', 'accessibility' in system search bar.

Comment: Thank you! My silly cat walked on my laptop and I had no idea what he did!!! LOL

Comment: Thanks:D ,for a moment I thought my ubuntu got hacked  and it seemed I accidently enable it :D

Comment: Thank you, this thing is really disturb me...

Answer (score 20):

Go to the Settings application. Select `Universal Access`. You will see a tab labeled "Seeing". In there should be `Screen Reader`. Turn that off.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem maybe, starting with Ubuntu 15.04. The Screen reader is off, same with the dispatcher setting; but it keeps telling me what I'm typing.

I have running four dispatcher, all at the time that can't be killed because they're starting again directly. To solve my problem, I went to System Settings -> Sound. On Applications, I muted the four speech-dispatcher.

Comment: Worked. But mine is Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I solved my speech-dispatcher not working issue! espeak was functionning normally but no sound was coming out of spd-say. It was a simple volume issue, went to the settings you mentioned and voila. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to change the systemwide settings for Speech Dispatcher? The (yes/no) systemwide settings for Speech Dispatcher can be changed by editing the `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher` file.

Open the terminal and from the terminal open the `/etc/default/speech-dispatcher` file for editing in nano text editor:

```
sudo nano '/etc/default/speech-dispatcher'
```

Find the lines in speech-dispatcher that say:

```
# Set to yes to start system wide Speech Dispatcher
RUN=yes
```

...and change `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no`.

This will disable the system wide speech dispatcher audible notifications, if they have been previously enabled. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the speech-dispatcher file. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

You can still toggle enable/disable the screen reader after it has been turned off systemwide by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: Sorry for the delayed acceptance!

Comment: mine is no and is still talking

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "orca" has bean launched. Kill the "orca" (Screen Reader) process, then you should hear "screen reader off".

Answer (score 1):

Go to universal access under settings then turn off the screen reader

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem with Laptop
My solution was simple
System -> Sound -> Application and  then I muted all four Speech-dispatcher
and it solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it in following ways :-

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

or goto **System Settings** > **Universal Access** > **Turn Off Screen Reader**

If you will check your **System Setting** > **Sound** > **Applications** then may be you can find that some instance of **Speech Dispatcher** is running. You can kill the running instances in this way:-

```
deepak@SpiritualDixit-PC:~$ ps aux | grep speech
deepak    2593  0.0  0.0 289004  5076 ?        Sl   10:10   0:00 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_dummy /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/dummy.conf
deepak    2599  0.0  0.0 289004  5008 ?        Sl   10:10   0:00 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_cicero /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/cicero.conf
deepak    2603  0.1  0.1 531004  9608 ?        Sl   10:10   0:03 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_espeak /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/espeak.conf
deepak    2632  0.0  0.0 289016  5024 ?        Sl   10:10   0:00 /usr/lib/speech-dispatcher-modules/sd_generic /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/generic.conf
deepak    2635  0.0  0.0 104284  2320 ?        Ssl  10:10   0:00 /usr/bin/speech-dispatcher --spawn --socket-path /run/user/1000/speech-dispatcher/speechd.sock --port 6560 --communication-method unix_socket
deepak    4708  0.0  0.0  21292   944 pts/9    S+   11:05   0:00 grep --color=auto speech
deepak@SpiritualDixit-PC:~$ kill 2593
deepak@SpiritualDixit-PC:~$ kill 2599
deepak@SpiritualDixit-PC:~$ kill 2603
deepak@SpiritualDixit-PC:~$ kill 2632
deepak@SpiritualDixit-PC:~$ kill 2635
deepak@SpiritualDixit-PC:~$ 
deepak@SpiritualDixit-PC:~$ ps aux | grep speech
deepak    4719  0.0  0.0  21292   944 pts/9    S+   11:06   0:00 grep --color=auto speech
deepak@SpiritualDixit-PC:~$
```

Comment: Also, mind the shortcut in the menu bar in gnome shell. Universal reader was disabled in my settings but enable in the menu bar

Answer (score 0):

On my Debian 12 as root

`apt remove orca`

did the trick.

It probably works the same in Ubuntu.